# Cordova media plugin able to record but unable to playback

Tags: cordova, plugins, audio-recording

I'm developing a communicator on Cordova, for windows store, windows phone 8.1, ios and android. I can't seem to playback my recorded media even though I followed the sample code in the docs. Help?

Answer (score 1):

I also faced the same kind of issue. When I used [media](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-media) plugin in my cordova project and tried to record & playback it was working fine in android but for iOS it was throwing error. So I used to save my recording into .wav file format and it fixed my issue. Make sure to add cordova plugin in your project before calling the media functions. Please have a look at my code.

```
function startRecord(){
 //to record voice and save us .wav
 var url = 'myrecording.wav';
 var cordovaRecorder = new Media(url,sucess,error);
 cordovaRecorder.startRecord('recorded-audio-'+id);
}

function playback(){
 //to playback recorded voice
 var url = 'myrecording.wav';
 var cordovaplayer = new Media(url,sucess,error);
 cordovaplayer.play();
}
```

Comment: what is the `startRecord` parameter for?